# Target all posts that are NOT aside or link post formats

Tags: post-formats

I want to add a post title to all of my posts apart from those that are marked as "aside" or "link" post formats.

I'm currently using this code to hide the post title for aside posts;

```
<?php if (! has_post_format('aside')) { ?>

    <?php the_title();?>

<?php } ?>
```

How can I target the "link" post format aswell using this method?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (!has_post_format('aside') && !has_post_format('link'))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:**

Now that I understand your question, try this...

Place this above your title to enable the post_class function.

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Then add `</div>` below your title (or excerpt, or wherever you want this special styling to end).

Now, a special class will be added in which you can use the classes for post formats.  for example, you may now use `.format-aside` in your CSS to style the aside.

Comment: That's not really practical for this as the rest of the post is styled the same, I just want to remove the titles from those 2 formats. Surely there's a way to combine 2 post formats using `if (! has_post_format())`...

Comment: @DeanElliott - please see my updated answer above.